# Does entity framework have the ability to pull environment variable values from the server?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, environment-variables

Just as an SSIS package/project can reference environment variables, is there anyway and application using entity framework can pull any of those values? Passwords, connection strings, etc? These are values I tend to put into app.config, but I think it would be great to have a global place to pull them from.

I don't really have any sample code, other than the application has entity framework data model in it.

I seem to find documentation regarding certain aspects of this, but nothing that cut and dry says I can say pull a password from an environment variable and use it within an application. This application is not client side.

Comment: `ConnectionString` in db? Then how to load the value first time?

Comment: @RezaAghaei in this case specifically, I am trying to pull a username and password that is under the SSISDB.

Comment: Using windows environment variables is deprecated in SSIS. I don't see how EF would be able to read variables from an environment in the SSIS catalog. It *certainly* doesn't have any built-in features for that (why should it?); at the most you could use a connection to query SQL Server system views, if there are any that disclose such sensitive information.

Comment: @GertArnold perfect. So that is really the answer I was looking for. Solid yes/no, and if yes a small example. I appreciate everyone's help. Gert if you make that an answer I can mark it. TBH you are right, why should it? But I have a very specific use for these values, for an extremely specific reason. Nevertheless, was looking for an out of the box functionality of EF, and it sounds like it does not exist.

Comment: But EF itself doesn't pull configuration strings from anywhere anyway. *You* need to tell EF what the configuration string is. It just so happens that most people pull it from the .config file.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I more of meant like, the model and connStr is already in app.config (added automatically when I added the model), but I was hoping I could add a model to say the SSISDB, and somehow pull those values. Again, did not know an out of the box solution wasn't available. Now I know :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read SSIS environment variables from C# using [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.EnvironmentInfo.Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.environmentinfo.variables?view=sqlserver-2017).

But it's not possible to pull the username and password from SSIS because you would need to authenticate to SSIS to read anything, which means you need to already know the username and password before connecting to SSIS.

You can read Windows environment variables using the [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable) method.

But if you are talking about settings specifically for your application, the app.config is the most appropriate place to put them. Although if you're talking about pulling values that you already know are in environment variables, then yeah, that's how you'd do it.

If you want to share settings between multiple distinct applications, you could look at making one of the app.config files hold the configuration for all of them, and use [`ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) in the other projects to open the other config file.

Or use the registry.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. But what if the solution has 6 projects that require this username/password combo. I have to add them all to the app.config for each project? And then if they ever change, I would need to update and build again correct or at least append the app.config file. That is really all I am trying to circumvent.

Comment: What type of solution is it? (ASP.NET, or are each individual applications?)

Comment: Individual C# applications. Also, not saying in this case it matters, but app.config is not entirely safe either I assume. So my idea was just as I make references to environment variables in an SSIS project, I was hoping to do the same here.

Comment: That is a great idea! I will give that a shot now. I appreciate you taking the time to look into this for me, and provide some alternatives!

Comment: You mentioned config files not being "safe". If you mean "secure", then you could look at [encrypting your connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#encrypting-configuration-file-sections-using-protected-configuration). But I've never actually done that and reading that makes my brain hurt, so I couldn't really help there. But it is possible to do.

Comment: Yeah secure == safe to me :). Again, its not a client application, so I think it may matter a bit less. Anyway, not sure if the other guy is going to create an answer, so if you could just add to yours that it is not possible to do what I am asking, or at least out of the box not possible, I think I could make it answered. Especially since you offered a good alternative :).

Comment: I've updated my answer. You *can* read SSIS environment variables from .NET, but it just logically won't work for what you want to use it for.